# How to return an Object from TimeLimiter instead of CompletableFuture

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, resilience4j

`resilience4j` `@TimeLimiter` returns `CompletableFuture` object... but I want the object.. how to make a work around... please need suggestions.

Comment: I mean, if you want to block, you can just call `get()` on it.  But that might defeat the point.

Comment: i wanted invoke `get()` but not from my client code.. but from Aspect... any way to override the `TimeLimiterAspect` ?